# Big Query parsing dates from string with only YY format - force Big Query to choose 1900s

Tags: date, parsing, google-bigquery

I have a table in Big Query with dates of birth that are string and written as dd-mmm-yy. When I am trying to parse the dates using parse_date("%d-%h-%y",DATE_OF_BIRTH), it is putting some of these dates of birth as a future date e.g. 25/07/2047 whereas what I need is 25/07/1947. I need some way of forcing big query to choose the century I want. I recognise that the documentation states that %y can be mixed with %C, though I don't know how to use it.

I have tried parse_date("%d-%h-%C20%y",DATE_OF_BIRTH) but that didn't seem to be right

Please note, I cannot at the moment get a new format for the date. This is what I am stuck with for the time being. I do however have another field called age that I can use to create a case when to try to ensure it picks the right century

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works for me. Posting in case it helps someone else:

```
CASE WHEN PARSE_DATE("%d-%b-%y", DATE_OF_BIRTH) <= CURRENT_DATE()
THEN PARSE_DATE("%d-%b-%y", DATE_OF_BIRTH)
ELSE DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE("%d-%b-%y", DATE_OF_BIRTH), INTERVAL 100 YEAR) END
```